# UITableViewCell custom initialization from nib

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uitableview, xib

How wrong could it be the code bellow:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in array) {

        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
            self = [currentObject retain];
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

I'm trying to bring up a custom UITableViewCell from nib file, the problem is that Leaks Instruments says there's a leak inside:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CPVideoGenTVCell *cell = (CPVideoGenTVCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[CPVideoGenTVCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.titleLbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.992 green:0.933 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];

    }

    CPTempVideo *aVideo = [self.videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.seasonLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Season %@", [self romanNumberFromArabic:aVideo.season]];
    cell.titleLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2i - \"%@\"",aVideo.idVideo, aVideo.chapterName];
    cell.managedImg.url = aVideo.thumbnail;

    [[CPDataManager sharedDataManager] manageImage:cell.managedImg];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code.

Comment: Did you run `Analyze`? It may give you a clue to where the leak is.

Comment: Analyze didn't show anything ... I think this code "should" work but its suspicious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an alternative I've found:

```
+ (id)cellWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in array) {

        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
            return currentObject;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

just return an autoreleased object and take care of that inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
CPTempHeadCell *headCell = (CPTempHeadCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:HeadCellIdentifier];
if (headCell == nil) {

    headCell = [CPVideoGenTVCell cellWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

think the problem is with retain, but don't understand why are you doing this crazy stuff with initWithStyle..

```
if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
  self = currentObject;
}
```

Comment: :D just overriding the initialization ... though there are cleaner ways to do it, I like to experiment. Your solution breaks the application inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Instruments tells you where exactly the leak is ... so you have to post exact line or block of code